# How to initalize 2 firebase on single application?

Tags: firebase

I am building a e-commerce website with admin dashboard.

Website using its own hosting, firestore and authentication.

Right now I am trying to get my admin dashboard to use its own hosting and authentication BUT using website firestore and I keep getting this error:

> index.esm.js:769 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named
> '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).

```
import firebaseAuthOnly from 'firebase/app' 
import firebase from 'firebase/app' 
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/functions";
import "firebase/analytics";
import "firebase/performance";

const firebaseAuthOnlyConfig = {
    apiKey           : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_API,
    authDomain       : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId        : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket    : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId            : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_APP_ID,
    measurementId    : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_MEASUREMENT_ID
}

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey           : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API,
    authDomain       : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL      : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId        : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket    : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId            : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId    : process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
}

// Initialize Firebase
firebaseAuthOnly.initializeApp(firebaseAuthOnlyConfig);
firebaseAuthOnly.analytics();
firebaseAuthOnly.performance();

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your different instances (Apps as Firebase calls them); by default you're working with the `[DEFAULT]` App, because that's the most common use case, but when you need to work with multiple Apps then you have to add a name when initialising:

```
// Intialize the "[DEFAULT]" App
var mainApp = firebase.intializeApp({ ... });

// Intialize a "Secondary" App
var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp({ ... }, "Secondary");
...
mainApp.database().ref("path/to/data").set(value);
secondaryApp.database().ref("path/to/data").set(anotherValue);
```

You can find a more example scenarios in the updated [Initialize multiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#initialize_multiple_apps) section of the Add Firebase to your JavaScript Project guide.